# How can I share SESSION between front and backend PHP?

Tags: php, session

I'm a bit new to loosely coupled methodologies, but I'm giving it a try. I have a PHP backend file that receives and responds to requests from the frontend. The problem is that the frontend is located at https://servername.com and the backend is http://localhost/backend.php

I want to check on the backend to make sure that a user I've validated is making the requests, but I haven't been able to figure out how to share sessions from front to backend. Basically, I want to know the userid of the operator making the requests so I can have the backend generate responses appropriately by access level.

I'm currently using curl to generate the request as such:

```
$ch= curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(['session_id'=>session_id()]));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/backend.php');
$response = curl_exec($ch)
```

Etc. I close it, return and so on, but this never works. Every time I send the session id and try to restore it on the backend, the transfer times out.

Restoring isn't supposed to be hard according to everything I'm reading:

```
if ($_REQUEST['session_id'])
   session_id($_REQUEST['session_id']);
session_start();
```

But it fails. If I send no session id, the communication works, but I don't have session information on the backend. If I send the id, it times out every time.

NOTE: I have tried changing the CURL url to https://localhost and servername with HTTPS but then I get an error: requested domain name does not match the server's certificate. Trying servername without HTTPS gives the same timeout issue I started with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the only thing I've been able to find that worked was to redirect PHP session calls to my DB instead. I used this guide: https://culttt.com/2013/02/04/how-to-save-php-sessions-to-a-database/

It explains that PHP's session class can be overridden so that it works exactly the same as normal, but on the backend, you're accessing your db instead. That way, all you have to do is send the session_id with each request to the backend and use session_id($the_id); on the backend before session_start() and both the front and backend will use the same session seamlessly (you can get and set variables back and forth as you would expect).

Absolutely every attempt I made to share cookies, pull up the same session, etc. failed miserably. Maybe it would work with remote servers, but I was only simulating a backend for front and backend separation on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `session_id()` on the frontend is determined by the frontend. The `session_id()` on the backend is determined by the backend. These do not match.

Sending the session id of the frontend to the backend will not grant you access to the session of the user on the backend. You would need to know the backend's session id, which you can't extract on the frontend.

There are 2 solutions;

1. The easiest solution is to make sure the backend and frontend are on the same domain (so www.example.com and backend.example.com). You can set the [cookie domain](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) for the session cookie to `.example.com`, so both will use the same session id.
2. Alternatively, the client needs to send the backend's session id to the frontend via the browser. The [Jasny SSO](https://github.com/jasny/sso) library does this.

[image: SSO workflow]

*Disclaimer; I'm the author of Jasny SSO.*

Comment: I'm not trying to access the backend users's session. There IS no backend user. The backend is only accessed by the frontend so basically the frontend IS the user? Bottom line I have session variables used on the front that I want to be able to access on the back. Are you saying there's no way to have the same session on the front and backend for a given user? Or is that what the cookie domain does? Would that work with multiple users using the site at the same time?

Comment: If there are no users on the backend and there is no UI on the backend, then there are no sessions on the backend. The session information on the frontend is stored locally (as files) by default. You'll need to send it to the backend. Alternatively, store them remotely (e.g. in Memcached). Than the backend can access it if you send the session id.

Comment: There's on UI for the backend, but I should be able to load sesson right? According to what I read, the same session can be recalled by using the session id of the frontend, but that's not working. What else can I do?

Comment: What you want to do only works if the frontend and backend are on the same server AND under the same domain. If they ARE on the same domain, but ARE NOT the same server you can use Memcached to store sessions. Otherwise, you need something like Jasny SSO.